# Python help: Evaluating if statements

Tags: python-2.7

Would like to seek help on the following code. Based on my understanding, one of the difference between using IF,ELIF,ELSE as compared to multiple ifs is that all IFs would be evaluated.

For the particular code below, I have a hard time understanding why inputting a value of 60 gives "You greedy bastard!" instead of "Man, learn to type a number."

My train of thought is as follows: If I key in 60, it is neither a 0 or 1, hence this won't be inputted into `how_much = int(next)` and should directly go to

```
else:
dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```

The second if statement should not be processed by Python because `how_much = int(next)` was skipped in the first if statement.

Full code:

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    if "0" in next or "1" in next:
        how_much = int(next)
    else:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` means "does the list,str,etc. include this value"? In this case, yes it does "60" includes a "0". However, if you were to enter "54" it would *NOT* include a "0" or "1" and so you'd reach your first exit condition.

You might want to consider casting how_much in a try/except block:

```
def gold_room():
    print "This room is full of gold. How much do you take?"

    next = raw_input("> ")
    try:
        how_much = int(next)
    except:
        dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
        return # I generally put a "return" statement in places like this one.

    if how_much < 50:
        print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win!"
        exit(0)
    else:
        dead("You greedy bastard!")
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation. I forgot that raw_input yields a string.

Answer (score 1):

When you enter `60` it is stored in `next` as a string.  `"0" in next` is `True`, because there is a zero in the string `"60"`, so `how_much` will get set to the integer `60`.

The following `if` will be True if `next` is a string of all digits:

```
if next.isdigit():
    how_much = int(next)
```

Another option is a `try/except`:

```
try:
    how_much = int(raw_input("> "))
except ValueError:
    dead("Man, learn to type a number.")
```